# Retrieve a json code and separate it by a box

Tags: php, json

I would like to retrieve a json code and separate it by a box. I have already tried with json decode but then I only get to see: Array...

If I do it the following way, I just get my json code. But I would like to separate them. As shown below

Sting DB:
["Apple","Strawberry"]

```
  <?php 
    $tag_sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT tags,id FROM users WHERE id = '". $user->id ."'");
    while ($my_tags = $tag_sql->fetch_object()){
        if ($tag_sql->num_rows > 0) { ?>

        <span class="tag"><span><?php echo $my_tags->tags; ?></span><a href="#" title="Removing tag">x</a></span>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <center><p>You have currently no tags available...</p></center>
  <?php }} ?>
```

What I need:
[image: What i need...]

What i have now..
[image: what i got now...]

I have searched on the Internet myself, but unfortunately without results. Perhaps you can help me further.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Site note: you need to use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) so that your queries are not vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming from your question that you mean you're storing the multiple tags in each database row as a JSON string. In which case you need to decode the JSON and loop through each tag to output the HTML.

```
<?php
    while ($my_tags = $tag_sql->fetch_object()) :
        if ($tag_sql->num_rows > 0) :
            $tags = json_decode($my_tags->tags, true);
            foreach ($tags as $tag) :
?>
            <span class="tag">
                <span><?php echo $tag; ?></span><a href="#" title="Removing tag">x</a>
            </span>
<?php
            endforeach;
        else :
?>
        <center><p>You have currently no tags available...</p></center>
<?php
        endif;
    endwhile;
?>
```